# Changing the Data Source of the Pivot table using macro in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am new to VBA and need to change the data source
Need to update the pivot table in Sheet1 worksheet in columns ‘Y’, ‘Z’ and‘AA’.
(With the analyse/Options tab of  Change Data Source)
Select all data in column ‘Q’ to column ‘W’ Of Sheet1 itself!
In short:- I need to change the data source of the pivot to 'Sheet1'!$Q$4:$W$1940. in column ‘Y’, ‘Z’ and‘AA’.

Please help with a working code (of macro -vba), I have been searching on google but no luck!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lots of q&a on here give working code about copying and pasting data - perhaps you need to look first.

Comment: You may find you can hack around this with [`INDIRECT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) if you don't need a great many values

Comment: How can indirect help ?